# Android: How to use the Html.TagHandler?

Tags: html, android, textview

I am trying to build an android application for a message board. To display formatted html for the post contents I have chosen the TextView and the Html.fromHtml() method. That, unfortunately, covers only a few html tags. The unknown tags are handled by a class that implements TagHandler and has to be generated by myself.

Now, I googled a lot and can't find an example of how this class should work. Let's consider I have an u tag for underlining some text (I know that this is deprecated, but whatever). How does my TagHandler look like?

It is called in the following way:

```
public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader) {
```

The first two arguments are fine. I guess I have to modify output using output.append(). But how do I attach something underlined there?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

So, i finally figured it out by myself.

```java
public class MyHtmlTagHandler implements TagHandler {

    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader) {
        if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("strike") || tag.equals("s")) {
            processStrike(opening, output);
        }
    }

    private void processStrike(boolean opening, Editable output) {
        int len = output.length();
        if(opening) {
            output.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), len, len, Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
        } else {
            Object obj = getLast(output, StrikethroughSpan.class);
            int where = output.getSpanStart(obj);

            output.removeSpan(obj);

            if (where != len) {
                output.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), where, len, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
    }

    private Object getLast(Editable text, Class kind) {
        Object[] objs = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), kind);

        if (objs.length == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            for(int i = objs.length;i>0;i--) {
                if(text.getSpanFlags(objs[i-1]) == Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK) {
                    return objs[i-1];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And for your TextView you can call this like:

```java
myTextView.setText (Html.fromHtml(text.toString(), null, new MyHtmlTagHandler()));
```

if anybody needs it.

Cheers

Comment: Nice. Though I don't understand it yet, the details can be dug up later.

Comment: I think I just used the Android documentation and put it together myself somehow. I couldn't find much on this topic then, but it might be easier now.

Comment: Because we are dealing with a closing tag.

Comment: @Lars this example can be found in the Android sdk. `android.text.html`. See my answer for line numbers.

Comment: Why do I need to create 2 StrikethroughSpans? Isn't it possible to create just a single one, and set its start and end correctly?

Comment: I have found that I need to wrap the whole string in a tag like `<html>`...`</html>` for this to handle the case when there is a start tag at the beginning of the string. This took me hours to figure out, so hopefully this tip will save someone time. If you don't do this, then the first tag will span the whole string because the end tag for the tag at the beginning will be ignored.

Comment: And for your TextView you can call this like: `myTextView.setText (Html.fromHtml(text.toString(), null, new MyHtmlTagHandler()));` (It took me a while to figure this out)

Comment: Html.FromHtml with the HtmlTagHandler overload is deprecated.

Comment: Do you know how to format the html String before adding spans? for example, if it's a `<pre>` tag, I need to replace `\n` with `<br \>` otherwise it won't add the line breaks. using the output seems the way to go but if I do a `output.toString().replace(…)` it doesn't work

Comment: @BlueMonkMN You save the day, it took me a whole day to figure out the reason when there is a tag of mine at the beginning of the string. But why the end tag will be ignored?

Answer (score 13):

### This solution is found in the [Android sdk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java)

In `android.text.html`. Lines 596 - 626. Copy/pasted

```
private static <T> Object getLast(Spanned text, Class<T> kind) {
    /*
     * This knows that the last returned object from getSpans()
     * will be the most recently added.
     */
    Object[] objs = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), kind);

    if (objs.length == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return objs[objs.length - 1];
    }
}

private static void start(SpannableStringBuilder text, Object mark) {
    int len = text.length();
    text.setSpan(mark, len, len, Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
}

private static <T> void end(SpannableStringBuilder text, Class<T> kind,
                        Object repl) {
    int len = text.length();
    Object obj = getLast(text, kind);
    int where = text.getSpanStart(obj);

    text.removeSpan(obj);

    if (where != len) {
        text.setSpan(repl, where, len, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

To use, override TagHandler like so:

```
public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader) {

    if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("strike") || tag.equals("s")) {

        if(opening){
            start((SpannableStringBuilder) output, new Strike();

        } else {
            end((SpannableStringBuilder) output, Strike.class, new StrikethroughSpan());
        }
    }       
}

/* 
 * Notice this class. It doesn't really do anything when it spans over the text. 
 * The reason is we just need to distinguish what needs to be spanned, then on our closing
 * tag, we will apply the spannable. For each of your different spannables you implement, just 
 * create a class here. 
 */
 private static class Strike{}
```

Comment: Do you know how to format the html String before adding spans? for example, if it's a `<pre>` tag, I need to replace `\n` with `<br \>` otherwise it won't add the line breaks. using the `output` seems the way to go but if I do a `output.toString().replace(…)` it doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

I took janoliver's answer and came up with my version that attempts to support more options

```
        String text = ""; // HTML text to convert
        // Preprocessing phase to set up for HTML.fromHtml(...)
        text = text.replaceAll("<span style=\"(?:color: (#[a-fA-F\\d]{6})?; )?(?:font-family: (.*?); )?(?:font-size: (.*?);)? ?\">(.*?)</span>",
                               "<font color=\"$1\" face=\"$2\" size=\"$3\">$4</font>");
        text = text.replaceAll("(?<=<font color=\"#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}\" )face=\"'(.*?)', .*?\"", "face=\"$1\"");
        text = text.replaceAll("(?<=<font color=\"#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}\" )(face=\".*?\" )size=\"xx-small\"", "$1size=\"1\"");
        text = text.replaceAll("(?<=<font color=\"#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}\" )(face=\".*?\" )size=\"x-small\"", "$1size=\"2\"");
        text = text.replaceAll("(?<=<font color=\"#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}\" )(face=\".*?\" )size=\"small\"", "$1size=\"3\"");
        text = text.replaceAll("(?<=<font color=\"#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}\" )(face=\".*?\" )size=\"medium\"", "$1size=\"4\"");
        text = text.replaceAll("(?<=<font color=\"#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}\" )(face=\".*?\" )size=\"large\"", "$1size=\"5\"");
        text = text.replaceAll("(?<=<font color=\"#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}\" )(face=\".*?\" )size=\"x-large\"", "$1size=\"6\"");
        text = text.replaceAll("(?<=<font color=\"#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}\" )(face=\".*?\" )size=\"xx-large\"", "$1size=\"7\"");
        text = text.replaceAll("<strong>(.*?)</strong>", "<_em>$1</_em>");  // we use strong for bold-face
        text = text.replaceAll("<em>(.*?)</em>", "<strong>$1</strong>");    // and em for italics
        text = text.replaceAll("<_em>(.*?)</_em>", "<em>$1</em>");          // but Android uses em for bold-face
        text = text.replaceAll("<span style=\"background-color: #([a-fA-F0-9]{6}).*?>(.*?)</span>", "<_$1>$2</_$1>");
        text_view.setText(Html.fromHtml(text, null, new Html.TagHandler() {
            private List<Object> _format_stack = new LinkedList<Object>();

            @Override
            public void handleTag(boolean open_tag, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader _) {
                if (tag.startsWith("ul"))
                    processBullet(open_tag, output);
                else if (tag.matches(".[a-fA-F0-9]{6}"))
                    processBackgroundColor(open_tag, output, tag.substring(1));
            }

            private void processBullet(boolean open_tag, Editable output) {
                final int length = output.length();
                if (open_tag) {
                    final Object format = new BulletSpan(BulletSpan.STANDARD_GAP_WIDTH);
                    _format_stack.add(format);
                    output.setSpan(format, length, length, Spanned.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
                } else {
                    applySpan(output, length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                }
            }

            private void processBackgroundColor(boolean open_tag, Editable output, String color) {
                final int length = output.length();
                if (open_tag) {
                    final Object format = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor('#' + color));
                    _format_stack.add(format);
                    output.setSpan(format, length, length, Spanned.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
                } else {
                    applySpan(output, length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                }
            }

            private Object getLast(Editable text, Class kind) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final Object[] spans = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), kind);

                if (spans.length != 0)
                    for (int i = spans.length; i > 0; i--)
                        if (text.getSpanFlags(spans[i-1]) == Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK)
                            return spans[i-1];

                return null;
            }

            private void applySpan(Editable output, int length, int flags) {
                if (_format_stack.isEmpty()) return;

                final Object format = _format_stack.remove(0);
                final Object span = getLast(output, format.getClass());
                final int where = output.getSpanStart(span);

                output.removeSpan(span);

                if (where != length)
                    output.setSpan(format, where, length, flags);
            }
        }));
```

This does seem to get the bullets, foreground color, and background color. It might work for the font-face but you might need to supply the fonts as it doesn't seem that Android supports fonts other than Droid/Roboto.

This is more of a proof-of-concept, you might probably want to convert the regex into `String` processing, since regex doesn't support combining the preprocessing in any way, meaning this takes a lot of passes over the `String`. This also doesn't seem to get the font size to change, I've tried defining it like "16sp", "medium", or "4" without seeing changes. If anyone has gotten sizes to work, mind sharing?

I currently would like to be able to add numbered/ordered list support to this, i.e.

1. item
2. item
3. item

**NOTE:**
To people starting with any of this, it seems that the "tag" that is given to `handleTag(...)` is just the name of the tag (like "span"), and doesn't contain any of the attributes assigned in the tag (like if you have "), you can see my loophole around this for the background color.

Comment: Aung Pyae you left an edit with a question, I can't answer why it is giving you an error with paragraph tags, unless the input is incorrect (though I thought Html.fromHtml(..) was using TagSoup to handle bad HTML). My code shouldn't be dealing with <p> tags at all, I was just letting the Html.fromHtml(..) deal with them. Maybe check a specific example where the error is happening, I can't say this is a complete implementation, if your input is doing something interesting it could be losing a tag in the preprocessing somewhere.

Comment: If you look for the ol/ul resolution still, add a field for parent, when you find the ul or ol  tag, set it to the tags name, then when you get the li, you can put up the bullit or a number, which you could also register in a field value. This way you'll have those covered.

Comment: I tried to use your code for ul and li. I only see one bulletpoint, and all the li are behind him on the same line. Does anybody has already fixed it ?

Answer (score 3):

We have been developing internally this library https://github.com/square1-io/rich-text-android for a while now and we use it in a number of content intensive news apps.

The library can parse most common html tags including video and img with remote download of images.
A custom view, RichTextView can then be used as a replacement of TextView to display the parsed content.

We have released it publicly just recently so the doc is still incomplete however the example provided should be easy to follow to see if it fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can see it it in Html.java API that style and text-align should be usable with the tags `<p>` , `<div>` etc. I am failing to get it to work with `<p align="center">` or `<p style="text-align: center">` and many other variants. Not being able to do this center alignment of text, and other styles like font size, multiple font faces from my ttf files, background colour, I have made my own htmlTextView based on TextView but with my own tagHandler class. Given one or two minor irritations, most of the tags are fine but my custom alignment tags, **left**, **centre**, **right** work only in special conditions (that I don't understand), otherwise. they don't work or crash the app! This is my alignment tag handle. It has the same structure as all the other custom tag handlers but really behaves weirdly! The basic form of my tag handlers are the same and **are not conceived by me**! I found the taghandler template after many hours searching on the web. I am grateful to whoever it was that posted it but my memory and organisational ability are such that I can't really remember who or where, so if you recognise this code as yours please let me know. The only link (which is here) I have is in my code:  [**stackoverflow**: Android: How to use the Html.TagHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044509/android-how-to-use-the-html-taghandler)

```
  private void ProcessAlignment(Layout.Alignment align, boolean opening, Editable output) {
    int len = output.length();
    if (opening) {
        output.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(align), len, len, Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
    } else {
        Object obj = getLast(output, AlignmentSpan.Standard.class);
        int where = output.getSpanStart(obj);

        output.removeSpan(obj);

        if (where != len) {
            output.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(align), where, len, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem is that the end tag is not getting connected the correct start tag.

```
private Object getLast(Editable text, Class kind) {
            Object[] objs = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), kind);

            if (objs.length == 0) {
                return null;
            } else {
                for (int i = objs.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                    if (text.getSpanFlags(objs[i]) == Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK) {
                        return objs[i];
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

This is the total class and something is not right. The largest component is my understanding! Perhaps someone can help me understand better...

```
public class htmlTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
static Typeface mLogo;
static Typeface mGAMZ;
static Typeface mChalk;
static Typeface mSouvenir;
int GS_PAINTFLAGS = FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG | ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG | HINTING_ON;

public htmlTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialise();
}

public htmlTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialise();
}

public htmlTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initialise();
}


private void initialise() {
    mLogo = Typeface.createFromAsset(theAssetManager, "fonts/logo.ttf");
    mGAMZ = Typeface.createFromAsset(theAssetManager, "fonts/GAMZ One.ttf");
    mChalk = Typeface.createFromAsset(theAssetManager, "fonts/swapfix.ttf");
    mSouvenir = Typeface.createFromAsset(theAssetManager, "fonts/Souvenir Regular.ttf");

    setPaintFlags(GS_PAINTFLAGS);
}

public void setDefaultTypefaceSouvenir() {
    setTypeface(mSouvenir);
}

public void setDefaultTypefaceGAMZ() {
    setTypeface(mGAMZ);
}

public void setDefaultTypefaceChalk() {
    setTypeface(mChalk);
}

/*public myTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}*/

public void setHTML(String htmltext) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) { // Nougat API 24
        setText(Html.fromHtml(htmltext, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY,
                null, new TypefaceTagHandler()));
    } else {
        setText(Html.fromHtml(htmltext, null, new TypefaceTagHandler()));
    }
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

@Override
public Bitmap getDrawingCache(boolean autoScale) {
    return super.getDrawingCache(autoScale);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
}

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044509/android-how-to-use-the-html-taghandler
private static class TypefaceTagHandler implements Html.TagHandler {


    private void ProcessAlignment(Layout.Alignment align, boolean opening, Editable output) {
        int len = output.length();
        if (opening) {
            output.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(align), len, len, Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
        } else {
            Object obj = getLast(output, AlignmentSpan.Standard.class);
            int where = output.getSpanStart(obj);

            output.removeSpan(obj);

            if (where != len) {
                output.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(align), where, len, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessTypefaceTag(Typeface tf, boolean opening, Editable output) {
        int len = output.length();
        if (opening) {
            output.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", tf), len, len,
                    Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
        } else {
            Object obj = getLast(output, CustomTypefaceSpan.class);
            int where = output.getSpanStart(obj);

            output.removeSpan(obj);

            if (where != len) {
                output.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", tf), where, len,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessScaleTag(float scalefactor, boolean opening, Editable output) {
        int len = output.length();
        if (opening) {
            output.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(scalefactor), len, len,
                    Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
        } else {
            Object obj = getLast(output, RelativeSizeSpan.class);
            int where = output.getSpanStart(obj);

            output.removeSpan(obj);

            if (where != len) {
                output.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(scalefactor), where, len,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessBox(int colour, boolean opening, Editable output) {
        int len = output.length();
        if (opening) {
            output.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(colour), len, len,
                    Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
        } else {
            Object obj = getLast(output, BackgroundColorSpan.class);
            int where = output.getSpanStart(obj);

            output.removeSpan(obj);

            if (where != len) {
                output.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(colour), where, len,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessTextColour(int colour, boolean opening, Editable output) {
        int len = output.length();
        if (opening) {
            output.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(colour), len, len,
                    Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
        } else {
            Object obj = getLast(output, ForegroundColorSpan.class);
            int where = output.getSpanStart(obj);

            output.removeSpan(obj);

            if (where != len) {
                output.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(colour), where, len,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
    }

    final HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader) {
        String Attr = "";
        //if (!opening) attributes.clear();
        processAttributes(xmlReader);

        if ("txt".equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
            Attr = attributes.get("clr");
            System.out.println("clr Attr: " + Attr + ", opening: " + opening);
            if (Attr == null || Attr.isEmpty()
                    || "black".equalsIgnoreCase(Attr)
                    || Attr.charAt(0) == 'k') {
                System.out.println("did black, opening: " + opening);
                ProcessTextColour(parseColor("#000000"), opening, output);
            } else {
                if (Attr.equalsIgnoreCase("g")) {
                    ProcessTextColour(parseColor("#b2b3b3"), opening, output);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("did colour, opening: " + opening);
                    ProcessTextColour(parseColor(Attr), opening, output);
                }
            }
            return;
        }

        if ("box".equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
            ProcessBox(parseColor("#d7d6d5"), opening, output);
            return;
        }


        if ("scl".equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
            Attr = attributes.get("fac");
            System.out.println("scl Attr: " + Attr);
            if (Attr != null && !Attr.isEmpty()) {
                ProcessScaleTag(parseFloat(Attr), opening, output);
            }
            return;
        }

        if ("left".equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
            ProcessAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, opening, output);
            return;
        }

        if ("centre".equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
            ProcessAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, opening, output);
            return;
        }

        if ("right".equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
            ProcessAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE, opening, output);
            return;
        }

        if ("logo".equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
            ProcessTypefaceTag(mLogo, opening, output);
            return;
        }
        if ("gamz".equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
            ProcessTypefaceTag(mGAMZ, opening, output);
            return;
        }

        if ("chalk".equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
            System.out.println("chalk " + (opening ? "opening" : "closing"));
            ProcessTypefaceTag(mChalk, opening, output);
            return;
        }
    }

    private Object getLast(Editable text, Class kind) {
        Object[] objs = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), kind);

        if (objs.length == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            for (int i = objs.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                if (text.getSpanFlags(objs[i]) == Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK) {
                    return objs[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void processAttributes(final XMLReader xmlReader) {
        try {
            Field elementField = xmlReader.getClass().getDeclaredField("theNewElement");
            elementField.setAccessible(true);
            Object element = elementField.get(xmlReader);
            Field attsField = element.getClass().getDeclaredField("theAtts");
            attsField.setAccessible(true);
            Object atts = attsField.get(element);
            Field dataField = atts.getClass().getDeclaredField("data");
            dataField.setAccessible(true);
            String[] data = (String[])dataField.get(atts);
            Field lengthField = atts.getClass().getDeclaredField("length");
            lengthField.setAccessible(true);
            int len = (Integer)lengthField.get(atts);

            /**
             * MSH: Look for supported attributes and add to hash map.
             * This is as tight as things can get :)
             * The data index is "just" where the keys and values are stored.
             */
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                attributes.put(data[i * 5 + 1], data[i * 5 + 4]);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception: " + e);
        }
    }

}

private static class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {
    private final Typeface newType;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
        super(family);
        newType = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
    }

    private void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
        int oldStyle;
        Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
        if (old == null) {
            oldStyle = 0;
        } else {
            oldStyle = old.getStyle();
        }

        int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
        if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        }

        if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
            paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
        }
        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

}

The htmlTextView is created from the activity with:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    theAssetManager = getAssets();
    htmlTextView tv = new htmlTextView(this);
    tv.setDefaultTypefaceSouvenir();
    tv.setTextColor(BLACK);
    tv.setBackgroundColor(0xfff0f0f0);
    tv.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
    tv.setTextSize(30);
    tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    tv.setHTML(getString(R.string.htmljumblies));
    //tv.setHTML(getString(R.string.htmltest));
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
    rl.addView(tv);
}
```

and **htmljumblies** is defined in strings.xml as below. This particular version will crash the app but if the first `<centre>`, `</centre>` tags are removed from lines 7 and 9, **The Jumblies** will appear centralised? Confusing and frustrating! Keep them and remove the `<centre>`, `</centre>` tags enfolding **The Jumblies** and nothing  happens. The line in the header is not centrally aligned!

```
    <string name="htmljumblies">
    <![CDATA[&DoubleLongRightArrow;<logo><scl fac="1.1"><font color="#e5053a">GAMZ</font></scl></logo>
        <chalk><scl fac="1.8"> SWAP </scl></chalk>
        <scl fac="1.00">Set <b>1</b>, Game <b>1</b></scl>
        <br>
        <centre>
        <gamz><font color="#e5053a"><scl fac="1.50">a</scl></font><scl fac="0.90">(9)</scl></gamz>, <gamz><font color="#00a3dd"><scl fac="1.50">e</scl></font><scl fac="0.90">(8)</scl></gamz>, <gamz><font color="#fba311"><scl fac="1.50">i</scl></font><scl fac="0.90">(8)</scl></gamz>, <gamz><font color="#bc5e1e"><scl fac="1.50">o</scl></font><scl fac="0.90">(8)</scl></gamz>, <gamz><font color="#bf30b5"><scl fac="1.50">u</scl></font><scl fac="0.90">(9)</scl></gamz>
        </centre>
        <br>
        This is an example of my custom <b>htmlTextView</b> drawn from HTML format
        text with custom tags to use custom fonts, colouring typeface sizing and highlight boxes.
        The default font is <b><i>Souvenir</i></b>, but 3 other fonts are used:<br>
        The <font color="#e5053a"><b><logo><scl fac="1.1">GAMZ</scl></logo></b></font>
        <font color="#000080"><gamz><scl fac="0.8"><box>letter</box>
        <box>fonts</box><sc></gamz></font>
        and <chalk><scl fac="1.8">swapfix</scl></chalk>, essentially
        <chalk><scl fac="0.9">Staccato 555</scl></chalk>,
        as used in the words <chalk><scl fac="1.2">SWAP</scl></chalk> and
        <chalk><scl fac="1.2">FIX</scl></chalk>
        on the <font color="#e5053a"><b><logo><scl fac="1.1">GAMZ</scl></logo></b></font>
        boxes.
        <br>
        <centre>
        <scl fac="2"><box><b> <u>The Jumblies</u> </b></box></scl><br>
        <font color="#0000ff">
        They went to sea in a Sieve, they did,<br>
        In a Sieve they went to sea:<br>
        In spite of all their friends could say,<br>
        On a winter\'s morn, on a stormy day,<br>
        In a Sieve they went to sea!<br>
        And when the Sieve turned round and round,<br>
        And every one cried, \'You\'ll all be drowned!\'<br>
        They called aloud, \'Our Sieve ain\'t big,<br>
        But we don\'t care a button! we don\'t care a fig!<br>
        In a Sieve we\'ll go to sea!\'<br>
        Far and few, far and few,<br>
        Are the lands where the Jumblies live;<br>
        Their heads are green, and their hands are blue,<br>
        And they went to sea in a Sieve.<br>
        <br>
        They sailed away in a Sieve, they did,<br>
        In a Sieve they sailed so fast,<br>
        With only a beautiful pea-green veil<br>
        Tied with a riband by way of a sail,<br>
        To a small tobacco-pipe mast;<br>
        And every one said, who saw them go,<br>
        \'O won\'t they be soon upset, you know!<br>
        For the sky is dark, and the voyage is long,<br>
        And happen what may, it\'s extremely wrong<br>
        In a Sieve to sail so fast!\'<br>
        Far and few, far and few,<br>
        Are the lands where the Jumblies live;<br>
        Their heads are green, and their hands are blue,<br>
        And they went to sea in a Sieve.<br>
        <br>
        The water it soon came in, it did,<br>
        The water it soon came in;<br>
        So to keep them dry, they wrapped their feet<br>
        In a pinky paper all folded neat,<br>
        And they fastened it down with a pin.<br>
        And they passed the night in a crockery-jar,<br>
        And each of them said, \'How wise we are!<br>
        Though the sky be dark, and the voyage be long,<br>
        Yet we never can think we were rash or wrong,<br>
        While round in our Sieve we spin!\'<br>
        Far and few, far and few,<br>
        Are the lands where the Jumblies live;<br>
        Their heads are green, and their hands are blue,<br>
        And they went to sea in a Sieve.<br>
        <br>
        And all night long they sailed away;<br>
        And when the sun went down,<br>
        They whistled and warbled a moony song<br>
        To the echoing sound of a coppery gong,<br>
        In the shade of the mountains brown.<br>
        \'O Timballo! How happy we are,<br>
        When we live in a Sieve and a crockery-jar,<br>
        And all night long in the moonlight pale,<br>
        We sail away with a pea-green sail,<br>
        In the shade of the mountains brown!\'<br>
        Far and few, far and few,<br>
        Are the lands where the Jumblies live;<br>
        Their heads are green, and their hands are blue,<br>
        And they went to sea in a Sieve.<br>
        <br>
        They sailed to the Western Sea, they did,<br>
        To a land all covered with trees,<br>
        And they bought an Owl, and a useful Cart,<br>
        And a pound of Rice, and a Cranberry Tart,<br>
        And a hive of silvery Bees.<br>
        And they bought a Pig, and some green Jack-daws,<br>
        And a lovely Monkey with lollipop paws,<br>
        And forty bottles of Ring-Bo-Ree,<br>
        And no end of Stilton Cheese.<br>
        Far and few, far and few,<br>
        Are the lands where the Jumblies live;<br>
        Their heads are green, and their hands are blue,<br>
        And they went to sea in a Sieve.<br>
        <br>
        And in twenty years they all came back,<br>
        In twenty years or more,<br>
        And every one said, \'How tall they\'ve grown!<br>
        For they\'ve been to the Lakes, and the Torrible Zone,<br>
        And the hills of the Chankly Bore!\'<br>
        And they drank their health, and gave them a feast<br>
        Of dumplings made of beautiful yeast;<br>
        And every one said, \'If we only live,<br>
        We too will go to sea in a Sieve,---<br>
        To the hills of the Chankly Bore!\'<br>
        Far and few, far and few,<br>
        Are the lands where the Jumblies live;<br>
        Their heads are green, and their hands are blue,<br>
        And they went to sea in a Sieve.</centre></font>
    ]]>
</string>
```