# personalize strikeThrough Textview

Tags: android, textview, text-size

I use this  to have stike through a textView

> textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

but now I wanna personalize the color and rotate it 45° to fit the diagonal of the content.

What I tied:

I though about extending the textview widget and override onDraw method .. but I'm very beginner at designing ...

so any help how to draw the red(color) rotated line on the textView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> adding to Mayani's response

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(strikeThroughColor);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    paint.setStrikeThruText(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(strikeThroughWidth);
    paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    float width = getWidth();
    float height = getHeight();
    canvas.drawLine(width / 10, height / 10, (width - width / 10), (height - height / 10), paint);
}
```

Comment: +1 Good to know you have tried and played more with my answer and found solution yourself.

Comment: I cannot get Strike through on text. line Draw Up Of the Text.

Answer (score 0):

For that, follow the below steps:

1. Create a **custom TextView** by extending `View` class
2. Declare this custom textview inside XML layout same like we do for TextView, Button widgets.

For example:

```
  class CustomTextView extends View {
        private int mColor;
        private int mRotationAngle, mRotationW, mRotationH;

            private String mText;
         public CustomTextView(Context context) { 
            super(context);
            // set default parameters
            mColor = Color.WHITE;
            mRotationAngle = 0;
         }

         public void SetColor(int newcolor) {
            mColor = newcolor;
            this.invalidate();
         } 

       public void SetRotation(int newangle, int neww, int newh) {
        mRotationAngle = newangle;
        mRotationW = neww;
        mRotationH = newh;
        this.invalidate();
    }

       public void SetText(String newtext) {
            mText = newtext;
            this.invalidate();
        }

    @Override 
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
            Paint paint = new Paint(); 
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); 
            canvas.rotate(mRotationAngle,mRotationW,mRotationH);
            canvas.drawText(mText, 0, 0, paint);
            super.onDraw(canvas); 
        } 
    }
```

**Update:**

Check for [Specifying “strikethrough” on a section of TextView text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301453/specifying-strikethrough-on-a-section-of-textview-text)

Comment: I didn't find to do what I need...anyway what is wrong with your code that made the strike trough not shown ? did u try it before posting it ?

Answer (score 0):

Using below approach you can achieve this functionality without messing with the UI in your java code:

```
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:text="$99"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview1"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textview1"
                        android:background="@color/fav_dark_red_color" />
                </RelativeLayout>
```