# How to change color of a strikethrough in android?

Tags: android, textview, paint

I am new to android. I tried the below code for strikethrough. But how can I change the color of the strikethrough(currently it is BLACK, I want it RED). I know its probably simpler but I could not find it even after googling much. Please help.Thanks in advance.

```
txtview.setText("Hello");
txtview.setPaintFlags(txtview.getPaintFlags()|Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: what api are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.4 Kitkat

Comment: A strikethrough is part of the font (it applies to the character) and you can't have a 2 colored character. The EASY solution that comes into my mind is to superimpose a second TextView, with a textColor set to RED and use that for  the strikethrough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is not possible for simple **textview** so you have to do the following:-

**1.Create a custom TextView by extending View class**

**2.Declare this custom textview inside XML layout same like we do for TextView.**

And at last write an **onDraw()** method like following.

```
    @Override
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(strikeThroughColor);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); 
        paint.setStrikeThruText(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strikeThroughWidth);
        paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        float width = getWidth();
        float heigh = getHeight();
        canvas.drawLine(width/10, heigh/10, (width-width/10),(heigh-heigh/10), paint);
}
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: @Anand.B:Is this answer is helpful to you or not???

Comment: @Anand.B atleast reply

Comment: thanks i gt it !!! sorry i gt busy so replied late!!

Comment: can you post some more code am having only one textview i need to apply offer price and actual price and also discount with different colors please help me

Comment: @Harsha are you found any solution for as per your requirement like display offer price and actual price in single textview??