# How to strike out a textview in android with specifc color

Tags: android

I have been trying to change the textview strike out line colour as RED but it gives me the same colur of the textview.
the code which I had tried is

```
Paint paint=new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
textview.setPaintFlags(holder.product_cost.getPaintFlags() | paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Please help me to fix this.

[image: Iam getting this]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439860/how-to-change-color-of-a-strikethrough-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881553/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strike-through-text-in-an-app-widget

Comment: Long answer short, you are unable to change the color of the default `textview` unless you create a custom `textview` and set the color on your own

Comment: [How to change color of a strikethrough in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25440124/3288182)

Comment: StrikethroughSpan is useful for handling this type of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Draw line throughout the `TextView` using `Ondraw` method.

```
    public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
        private int mColor;
        private Paint paint;

        public CustomTextView (Context context) {
            super(context);
            init(context);
        }

        public CustomTextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init(context);
        }

        public CustomTextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            init(context);
        }

        private void init(Context context) {
            Resources resources = context.getResources();
            //Color
            mColor = resources.getColor(R.color.blue);

            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(mColor);
            //Width
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawLine(0, 25, getWidth(), 25, paint);
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
<package.CustomTextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Strike Me"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>
```

*You can customize the positioning of strike and you can do as follows if you need to strike with the color of TextView that you applied.*

**Using resource file**

```
<resource>
    <string id="@+id/strike_one"><strike>Strike Me!</strike></string>
</resources>
```

**Programmatically**

```
TextView text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_label);
text.setText("Strike Me!");
text.setPaintFlags(text.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use onDraw method

```
@Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(strikeThroughColor);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); 
    paint.setStrikeThruText(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(strikeThroughWidth);
    paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    float width = getWidth();
    float heigh = getHeight();
    canvas.drawLine(width/10, heigh/10, (width-width/10),(heigh-heigh/10), paint);
}
```

refer of this link : [How to change color of strikethrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439860/how-to-change-color-of-a-strikethrough-in-android)