# Converting HTML Bullets to PlainText

Tags: java, android, html, html-parsing

I'm in the process of creating an app for android, and one of the things it does is take existing Html on a server and uses TextView to display it to the user. Most Html tags are fine (e.g. bold), but things like unordered lists (aka bullets) are not rendered properly when using `Html.fromHtml(txt)`

I noticed that a [BulletSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BulletSpan.html) exists in the android docs. However, there is absolutely no explanation as to how to use it properly.

Will the BulletSpan indeed help me, and how can I go about using it?

Finally, if it won't help me, how can I go about changing all the lists to have asterisks in the front of them (like markdown does) in Java?

Please don't answer to use webview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code for `android.text.Html` (available at [here](https://android.googlesource.com)), it looks like the following tags are converted by `fromHtml(String)`.

- br, p, div, em, b, strong, cite, dfn, i, big, small, font, blockquote, tt, a, u, sup, sub, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, img

Some of these tags have additional attributes that are converted.  For example, the following values for the font color attribute are converted.

- aqua, black, blue, fuchsia, green, grey, lime, maroon, navy, olive, purple, red, silver, teal, white, yellow

Unfortunately, I've not found where this information is documented.

To transform additional tags, such as ul and li, you'll need to supply an appropriate implementation of [Html.TagHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.TagHandler.html), for which [Google searching](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=android+Html.TagHandler) turns up [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044509/android-how-to-use-the-html-taghandler).

This hopefully is enough information on how to handle the translation.  Whether to use `BulletSpan`, I cannot offer any advice, as I don't know that I've ever seen one in action, and [Google searching for android "BulletSpan example"](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=android+%22BulletSpan+example%22) turns up zero matches.  Internally in the non-public class `android.content.res.StringBlock`, `BulletSpan` is used to represent a list item.  So, its use looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with the limited control that Html.fromHtml() gives you and I finally gave up.

I was already using HtmlCleaner to clean up the Html before feeding it to Html.fromHtml() and I just implemented a direct conversion to a Spanned. This way I had full control over how elements were rendered, though I did copy a lot from the original Html class.

HtmlCleaner will parse Html to a tree of TagNode objects, and I implemented a CleanHtmlParser.fromTageNode() method. It's here:

https://github.com/NightWhistler/PageTurner/blob/master/src/net/nightwhistler/pageturner/html/CleanHtmlParser.java

BulletSpan gave me some mixed results because it renders the bullets on the left of the line and then indents the text instead of indenting both text and bullets. I just wrapped them in a margin and printed a unicode bullet character in front of the text.

Comment: Do you need to use HtmlCleaner on your HTML? Html.fromHtml() is using TagSoup to handle "dirty" HTML already, so it seems like your HTML will be processed twice.

Comment: By now it evolved into a seperate project, which is a drop-in replacement for Html.fromHtml(): http://github.com/NightWhistler/HtmlSpanner

Comment: Your library looks sweet. I cannot wait to use it.