# Android: Render HTML not supported by Html.fromText

Tags: android, html, webview, textview

If I have html with tags not supported as part of `Html.fromText` I understand a `WebView` will do the trick as it supports standard HTML as a browser but its performance is really slow to my liking. So if I don't want to use `WebView`, the only other way is to parse the HTML myself and put different tags in muliple `TextView` inside a vertical `LinearLayout`?

Comment: I believe the Android OS takes care of parsing the tags in a TextView. Have you tried displaying it in a TextView?

Comment: That would depend a bit on the "tags not supported" that you want to support. There is no way you are going to support `<iframe>`, for example, using `TextView` in any form or fashion.

Comment: @Sana Yes I tried displaying it in `TextView` and it did not render.
@CommonsWare I am trying to support <pre /> and <code /> which are not getting rendered in `TextView`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use [`Html.fromHtml()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler%29) with an [`Html.TagHandler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.TagHandler.html) to handle unknown tags like `<pre/>` and `<code/>`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4062318/165674) for an example of how to implement `Html.TagHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`replaceAll()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to convert the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags to `<tt>`, which is supported by `Html.fromHtml()`. Then, use `Html.fromHtml()` to create the `SpannedString` that you pass to the `TextView`.