# div tag with Html.fromhtml

Tags: android, html

I have read from various blogs that div tag is supported by Html.fromHtml but it doesn't support **style** attribute.

What i want to do is to assign a background color as specified by the string which contains the html tags. Something like

```
    <p style="background-color:green;">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

If style attribute is not supported by Html.fromHtml(), is there any other way such that I can change the bgcolor using html tags.

Thanks.

Comment: Dont just post a whole story... post code and things that you have tried ..that way its helpful for everyone. Thanks

Comment: Thanks..I made some changes regarding that.

Comment: you should use Html.TagHandler

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044509/android-how-to-use-the-html-taghandler][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044509/android-how-to-use-the-html-taghandler

Answer (score 0):

use the code:

```
 yourfield.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ca1216"));
```

Comment: I want to extract details from the string and then set the attributes