# Android Html.fromHtml tag "strike" does not works

Tags: android, html, strikethrough, fromhtml

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4062318/4145376)

and it doesn't works for me.
What I am doing wrong?
I used it:

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<strike>111</strike> 222", null, new MyHtmlTagHandler());
```

but "111" showing as not strike out(

sorry if I am wrong, I am nub here)

Comment: @Blackbelt: Yes, but he's using a `TagHandler` that is supposed to support it.

Comment: I missed that, sorry,

Comment: I do not see anything obviously wrong in your code snippet here. I have no idea if that `TagHandler` actually works. If you're willing to restrict yourself to XHTML, you're welcome to look at [my nascent CWAC-RichTextUtils library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richtextutils), which definitely supports `<strike>`.