# Formatting for <pre> tag with white space and line breaks Android

Tags: android, html

I was able to set my own Tag Hanlder using this example: [Android: How to use the Html.TagHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044509/android-how-to-use-the-html-taghandler)

Everything worked until I hit this example:

```
<pre class="prettyprint linenums">    Some Code()\n   more code </pre>
```

This is transformed into

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(context, html, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT, null, CustomTagHandler())
```

The `fromHtml` method can't seem to handle the white space and `\n` it will ignore both and skip setting any Span on this tag.

My only option is to replace the white space and `\n` BEFORE calling `fromHtml` with the following:

```
html.replace("  ", "&nbsp;&nbsp;")
    .replace("\n", "<br />")
```

This is to me is a bad solution. First, not all of the Htmls will have a pre tag, and it skips single spaces, because it will replace to this `<pre&nbsp;class...` which would fail all together.

I tried editing the `handleTag` method in the CustomTagHandler which has the output

```
  Some Code()\n   more code
```

but replace the String there doesn't work.

Any suggestions on setting a Span for tags that have white space and line breaks?

The goal is to preserve the line breaks and white space and add a Monospace to the text.