# Android Spanned text is blank on TextView

Tags: android, textview, spannable, spanned

I am using Spanned object to process some HTML tags and showing the resulted text on TextView. But the Text is blank on TextView.

```
final Spanned output = Html.fromHtml(element.getText(), null,
                    new ElementTagHandler(element));

            textView.setText(output);
```

In the textView if I set a constant string, Its working as expected

```
            textView.setText("Hello");  \\ works perfectly
```

But when I pass in Hello its showing blank TextView.

```
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/view123"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"/>
```

Am I missing any flag that needs to be updated?

Comment: Kind of hard to debug this without the text.  Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simpler like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37905107/12546733)

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Spanned fromHtml(String html){
    if(html == null){
        // return an empty spannable if the html is null
        return new SpannableString("");
    }else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        // FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY is the behaviour that was used for versions below android N
        // we are using this flag to give a consistent behaviour
        return Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
        return Html.fromHtml(html);
    }
}
```

while html variable can consist of a string with html tags such as ,  etc...

but if you insist you can do something like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4062318/12546733)

Comment: Thanks @DemoDemo for commenting. I tried the above solution but no luck :(

Comment: what is the value of element.getText()?

Comment: It returns proper text. On Android studio I tried viewing the textview in layout inspector, I could see the text set to textview

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to try this one?

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(element.getText()), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

I hope this helps.